# Is the javadoc on String.chars() and String.codePoints() incorrect?

Tags: java, string, javadoc, java-8

Looking at the `String.chars()` method in Java 8, we can see the following [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--):

> default IntStream chars()
>
> Returns a stream of int zero-extending the char values from this sequence. Any char which maps to a surrogate code point is passed through uninterpreted.
>
> If the sequence is mutated while the stream is being read, the result is undefined.
>
> Returns:
> an IntStream of char values from this sequence
> Since:
> 1.8

As we can see, we had to find this javadoc in `CharSequence`, as it was not redefined in `String`. The same arguments here also hold for `String.codePoints()`.

The javadoc describes that:
**If the sequence is mutated while the stream is being read, the result is undefined.**

But Strings (as opposed to `CharSequence`) are immutable, hence is the javadoc incorrect here for the `String` class? My feeling is that it is still correct under logic, but it also kind of implies that the `chars[]` in `String` can be mutated, which goes directly against immutability.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it's only a language-related, semantic problem. The javadoc applies to any char sequence, mutable or not. It says that **if** the sequence is modified, then the result of these methods is undefined.

It happens that when calling this method on a String, there is no way for the sequence to be modified, because Strings are immutable.

The above doesn't imply that Strings lose immutability because of this method.

Just like the sentence "if an animal has legs, then it can walk" doesn't imply that all animals have legs.

Comment: I should have added that it may imply immutability of strings on users not familiar with reasoning logic. I still think it's formulated dubiously.

Comment: Users not familiar with reasoning logic should get familiar with it before considering programming, IMHO. Programming is all about logic.